# How can I get RecursiveSearch() to return the modified data dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, replace

**Disclaimer**: I've been at this for about a week, and it's entirely possible that I've come up with the solution, but I missed it in my troubleshooting. Also, the INI files can be over 200 lines long and 10 deep with combinations of dictionaries and lists.

**Situation**: I maintain a couple dozen applications, and each application has a JSON formatted INI file that tracks certain system settings. On my computer, I aggregated all those INI files into a single file and then collapsed the structure. That collapsed structure is the unique keys from all those INI files, followed by all the possible values that each key has, and then what I may want each value to be replaced with (see examples below).

**Goal**: When I need to make configuration changes in those applications, I want to instead make the value changes in my JSON file and then use a Python script to replace the matching key-value pairs in all those other system files.

**Simplifications**:

1. I understand opening and writing the files, my problem is the parsing.
2. The recursion will always end with a key-value pair where the type(value) is str.

## Sample INI file from one of those applications

```
{
    "Version": "3.24.2",
    "Package": [
        {
            "ID": "42",
            "Display": "4",
            "Driver": "E10A"
        }, {
            "ID": "50",
            "Display": "1",
            "Driver": "E12A"
        }
    ]
}
```

## My change file

**Example use**: If I want to replace all instances of {"Display":"1"} with {"Display":"10"}, then all I have to do is put a 10 between the double quotes below ... {"Display": {"1": ""}} to {"Display": {"1": "10"}}

```
{
    "Version" {
        "3.24.2": "",
        "42.1": "",
        "2022-10-1": ""
    },
    "ID" {
        "42": "",
        "50": ""
    },
    "Display": {
        "1": "",
        "4": ""
    },
    "Driver": {
        "01152003.1": "",
        "E10A": "",
        "E12A": ""
    }
}
```

## Attempt 1

I read that Python assigns values like a C *pointer, but that was not my experience with this attempt. There are no errors, and the data variable never changed.

```
def RecursiveSearch(val, key=None):
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for k, v in val.items():
            RecursiveSearch(v, k)
    elif isinstance(val, list):
        for v in val:
            RecursiveSearch(v, key)
    elif isinstance(val, str):
        # Is the key being tracked in my change file
        if key in ChangeFile:
            # Is that key's value being tracked in my change file
            if val in ChangeFile[key].keys():
                # Find the matching key-value and apply the replacement value
                for k, v in ChangeFile[key].items():
                    # Only replace the value if it has something to replace it with
                    if k == val and v != "":
                        key[val] = v


data = open('config.ini', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
data = convertJSON(data)
ChangeFile = open('change.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
ChangeFile = convertJSON(data)


data = RecursiveSearch(val=data, key=None)
print(data)
```

## Attempt 2

Same code but with return values. In this attempt the data is completely replaced with the last key-value pair the recursion looked at.

```
def RecursiveSearch(val, key=None):
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        for k, v in val.items():
            tmp = RecursiveSearch(v, k)
            if tmp != {k: v}:
                return tmp
        return val
    elif isinstance(val, list):
        for v in val:
            tmp = RecursiveSearch(v, key)
            if v != tmp:
                return tmp
        return val
    elif isinstance(val, str):
        # Is the key being tracked in my change file
        if key in ChangeFile:
            # Is that key's value being tracked in my change file
            if val in ChangeFile[key].keys():
                # Find the matching key-value and apply the replacement value
                for k, v in ChangeFile[key].items():
                    # Only replace the value if it has something to replace it with
                    if k == val and v != "":
                        return v
                    else: return val
                else: return val
            else: return val
        else: return val
    # Return edited data after the recursion uncoils
    return {key: val}


data = open('config.ini', 'w', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
data = convertJSON(data)
ChangeFile = open('change.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
ChangeFile = convertJSON(data)


data = RecursiveSearch(val=data, key=None)
print(data)
```

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm done making changes. I went through so many attempts that it's hard pulling out the bugs I created between each attempt :D

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The recursion is working, but it's not passing the modifications back out of the definition. All the changes appear to be scoped locally

Comment: In the first attempt, the data never changed. In the second attempt, the recursion replaced the entire variable with the last key-value pair it found.

and thanks for checking out my problem :)

Comment: Okay, and now what is the question? Stack Overflow is meant as a repository of questions and answers useful to many programmers in the future. Which question do you want to add to this repository?

Comment: I pass "data" into the recursion, how do I get the modified "data" back out so that I can export it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trolling. "How do I get the modified data back out" would be a question that you should edit into your post and focus it around this question. Currently your post contains a description of what you are trying to achieve overall but not an actual, specific, question. Also see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @mkrieger Thank you for explaining that, I was very burned out and tired last night. I just now updated the Title to be a question. In the future I will try defining the complexity of the problem in the keywords, such as [dictionary][nested-lists][recursion], and see if that gets a better result instead of putting it into the title.